# Open tabs not stacking in toolbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do i stop items from appearing across the screen. I want them to show stacked like the picture below, however we have had two new computers and they are displaying all across the screen instead. i have unticked the aero peak and desktop composition which has worked on all the other computers but not the new ones.

Using windows 7.

.
[image]

Comment: There is a threshold before it will display stacked, below this it will be horizontal, i think it is 8

Comment: on one of the computers we have 13 but its all horizontal :(

Comment: [How to Enable or Disable Grouping of Taskbar Buttons in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104774-enable-disable-grouping-taskbar-buttons-windows.html).

Comment: Just checked, it is 16 folders, when I delete one and there are 15 it reverts to horizontal.

Comment: @JosefZ  They are using Windows 7

Comment: @Moab All _Taskbar Button Grouping Options_ are the same for Windows 7,8 +10. The 6th paragraph in provided link says (literally) _This tutorial will show you how to enable or disable grouping of taskbar buttons for specific or all users in **Windows 7**, Windows 8, and Windows 10._ Of course, the [setting panel differs in Win7](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/prevent-windows-7-from-combining-taskbar-application-icons/)…